# troubleshoot ie flash 404

Tags: flash, firefox, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, http-status-code-404

Hello I am having some trouble with a clients website. He uses wimpy player to load a playlist of his own hosted music. I've set up a test to demonstrate the behavior [here](http://markmaxwellmusic.com/wimpytest/player.html) . If you visit the site in firefox, everything works. If you visit in IE it doesn't. Further investigation shows that it can read the playlist, and makes a valid request for an mp3, but when it comes from the swf loaded in IE7, the server returns a 404. If the request is made by the swf loaded in FF, the file is returned appropriately. Furthermore, entering a url to one of the mp3's in IE7 manually allows me to download it. The only difference I could see is in IE7 the swf includes a referrer (itself). I am using the proxy in burp suite to capture the requests and responses in IE7 and firebug to do the same in FF. Any insight? Is there a better place to ask this type of question?

Answer (score 0):

I dug deeper. The client had a condition in their htaccess to not allow referred access to their mp3's. The IE request had a referrer. whoops.